# Prove if $\sum na_n$ converges, then $\sum |a_n|^p$ converges, where $p>1$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

My attempt was to show that $a_n$ has to be bounded by the series $\frac{1}{n^q}$ and $-\frac{1}{n^q}$, where $q>2$, at least after some point in the sequence. This because $n\cdot\frac{1}{n^q}=\frac{1}{n^p}$, and $\sum\frac{1}{n^p}$ converges. Therefore $|a_n|<\frac{1}{n^2},$ which converges. I don't know why, however, the inclusion of $p>1$ is necessary in the proof, so I think I'm doing this wrong.

Comment: Why do you need $q>2$? You have that $|a_n|<\frac{1}{n}$ for $n$ large, since $na_n\to 0$. Then $|a_n|^p<\frac{1}{n^p}$ and $\sum \frac1 {n^p}$ converges for $p>1$.

Comment: Technically, you only really need that $na_n$ is bounded...

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $\sum na_n$ converges.

For all $\epsilon > 0$, there exists an $N > 0$ such that for all $n > N$, 
$$|na_n| < \epsilon\text{.} $$
This is due to the fact that convergence of $\sum na_n$ implies $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}na_n = 0$. 
It follows that, under these same conditions, since $|na_n| = |n||a_n|=n|a_n|$, 
$$|a_n| < \dfrac{\epsilon}{n}\text{.}$$
Since this is true **for all** $\epsilon > 0$, we may take $\epsilon_0 := 1$ and notice that
$$|a_n| < \dfrac{1}{n}\implies |a_n|^p<\dfrac{1}{n^p}\text{.}$$
Since $|a_n|^p > 0$ and $\dfrac{1}{n^p} > 0$ for all $n$, we may use the limit comparison test.

It is well-known that $\sum\dfrac{1}{n^p}$ converges only for $p > 1$. (See [$p$-series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(mathematics)#p-series).)  Thus, by limit comparison, $\sum |a_n|^p$ converges as well for $p > 1$.